# Statically initialized array?

Tags: java, arrays, coding-style

I was using a the reviewer "codePro Tools" by google 
and it flagged the flowing:

```
new Object[] { max }
```

with "Statically initialized array"

Explanation:

An array initializer is being used to initialize an array.

Recommendation

1. The array should be initialized dynamically.

are there a good reason for this? or is just better to ignore.

this flag is on a section of rules called "code style".

Thanks

Comment: I use static initialisers frequently.  I believe that in certain situations they can make structures clearer.

Comment: Does it go away when you declare the variable final?

Comment: @michael667 I assume not looking at the doc: http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/audit/audit_rules_com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.auditGroup.codingStyle.html#com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.audit.disallowArrayInitializers

Comment: final Object[] var =  new Object[] { max }; nope flagged as well.

Comment: Well rule disabled... after listen your opinions. I just want to be sure i wasn't missing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always: it depends. It's a question of style. I personally can't see anything wrong with this at all. In this case, I think it would just obscure the code to initialise it dynamically.

I use statically initialized arrays all of the time. Code style is very subjective and varies from project to project, not just from person to person. It's up to you to decide whether it's a good thing for your project.

Answer (score 2):

Take all automated code inspection tools with a grain of salt.  They make recommendations, not issue commands.

If you have a good reason for writing your code that way, and can articulate it well to yourself and others, then stick with your code and ignore CodePro.